# MS Sql - Update table 1 based on table 2 and table 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update table 1 based on table 2 and table 3. Right now am updating it in two separate statements.

Is it possible to update table 1 first based from table 2 then for the NULLS to be updated from table 3 all in a single update using join.

I have tried to build a query but where to include

> tbl1.col1=tbl3.col1

```
update tbl1
set    tbl1.col1= tbl2.col1 
from   table1 tbl1
  left JOIN table2 tbl2 
    ON tbl1.col = tbl2.col
  left JOIN table3 tbl3 
    on tbl1.col=tbl3.col and tbl2.col<>tbl3.col
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `coalesce()`:

```
update tbl1
    set col1 = coalesce(tbl2.col1, tbl3.col1)
    from table1 tbl1 left join
         table2 tbl2 
         on tbl1.col = tbl2.col left join
         table3 tbl3
         on tbl1.col = tbl3.col and tbl2.col <> tbl3.col;
```

Comment: Thank you, will the query achieve what am looking for, am little confused about it

Comment: What are you confused about? Those are valid queries.

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz - Took time to realize I can click on that grey tick mark

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` both returns the first `NOT NULL` value

Try this

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET    tbl1.col1 = COALESCE(tbl2.col1, tbl3.col1) -- ISNULL(tbl2.col1, tbl3.col1)
FROM   table1 tbl1
       LEFT JOIN table2 tbl2
              ON tbl1.col = tbl2.col
       LEFT JOIN table3 tbl3
              ON tbl1.col = tbl3.col
                 AND tbl2.col <> tbl3.col
```

Comment: Thank you, will the query achieve what am looking for, am little confused about it.